# Why does it find nil while unwrapping Optional? Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, runtime-error

So I have a tableview using core data, when I choose a cell, it segues to another VC and sends across the "goal" class item from CoreData that corresponds to the selected cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGoalPopup", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toGoalPopup" {

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! goalPopupViewController

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            destinationVC.selectedGoal = goals[indexPath.row]
            print(destinationVC.selectedGoal)

        }
    }
}
```

At this point the console prints the values for the selectedGoal's name, value, dateAdded, and status, so I know it is setting properly.

In the destinationVC -

```
@IBOutlet weak var goalTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var goalValueLabel: UILabel!

var selectedGoal: Goal? {
    didSet{
        if let name = selectedGoal?.name {
            goalTitleLabel.text = name
        }
    }
}
```

I get the "Fatal error, unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional..." message.

How can it be nil when I proved that it has been set?

Thanks heaps for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nil` here is not the value you set, but the `goalTitleLabel`. You're setting the value when the view is not yet loaded (thus IUO value of `goalTitleLabel` is `nil`). It's probably better to set the label's `text` property in `viewDidLoad`.

If you plan updating the sent object and renewing display value, then you'd need an extra condition to check `isViewLoaded`.

You can also call `loadViewIfNeeded` in `prepareForSegue`, but that, IMHO, is a code smell.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer.  First time posting a question, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to "Accept" (click the checkmark under the downvote arrow) the answer in the future if it solves your problem.